# query with include, but only in certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to make a Model query in rails with an include statement, but to have the "include" only if another condition occurs?

I have this code:

```
@families = Family.find(:all,
:conditions => family_conditions, 
:select => 'families.id,families.name', 
:include => families_include_array)
```

So the include should be there only if the families_include_array is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your query in an if statement

```
if families_include_array.is_nil?
  @families = Family.find(:all,:conditions => family_conditions, :select => 'families.id,families.name')
else
    @families = Family.find(:all,:conditions => family_conditions, :select => 'families.id,families.name', :include => families_include_array)
end
```

Or you can create your SQL request as string and send it to SQL with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`

**UPDATE**

Or you can try to override the find method

```
def self.find(*args)
  records = super  
  # Manipulate records
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I am looking for the smarter way rails is known for.

Comment: There no way to include a condition statement directly in a method call. But you can try to override the find method.

Comment: I think you are likely to discover that when you add the :include parameter, your :select parameter will be ignored and the full complement of joined columns will be returned.  This is a long-standing bug.

Comment: @KenB As a matter of a fact, I find all rails way of query to be very clumsy. The rails model queries are very good for VERY simple queries, but when your query is complicated, the best way is the old way - write your own!